# Filling 2" gap between a tub and existing floor tiles for 30" bathtub in 32" tub opening

Tags: tile, bathtub, grout, remodeling

As the title suggests, I have a 30" tub in a 32" tub opening.  When the tub is centered, there is an inevitable 2" gap between the tub skirt and the existing floor tiles.  The 2" gap excludes the 3/8" end grout line, which used to butt against the old tub.  The existing tiles are laid on top of another layer of (old) tiles, thereby raising the tiled part of the floor by about an 1".

What are the possible lasting, preferably the least time consuming, ways to close this gap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2" of tile - after that it's decorating (i.e. try to match and trim 2" chunks to fit of the tile you find that most closely matches the tiles you have; 2" of "border" tiles, 2 rows of 1" tile (perhaps checkerboard-patterned) the options are endless.) Thinset, tile (with or without lots of trimming), grout, possibly sealer.

A space that small won't really be too time consuming even with all the needed steps. I can't think of a faster way that will stand a chance of lasting and looking decent, but if you want to be the guy that fills it with caulk, I'm not stopping you, simply advising that it might not prove suitable or attractive.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I now have a clear direction, but one more thing.  I remeasured the depth of the gap and it's actually 2" from the plywood subfloor to the existing tiles line.  I'd imagine putting lots mortar directly to build up height would be a bad idea.  Would using cement be an acceptable way?